# How to build jar when a project depence on other project with gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a project in Intellij Idea.
The root directory sturcture is like this:

```
MyProject:
  --ProjectA
       --build.gradle

  --ProjectCommon
       --build.gradle

  --settings.gradle
```

The ProjectA will use ProjectCommon's class.

The contents of `setting.gradle` are as follows:

```
rootProject.name = 'MyProject'

include 'ProjectA'
include 'ProjectCommon'
```

the dependencies code snippet of ProjectA's `build.gradle`:

```
  compile project(':ProjectCommon')
```

I use ProjectCommon's class in ProjectA. It is work and run successfully When I run with Intellij idea run configuration. Howerver There are some error when I build ProjectA.jar with gradle's **build task**.The error is that ***error: package com.common.xxx not exist***. (com.common package is in ProjectCommon and I use it's class in ProjectA).

How to configure the gradle so can I build the ProjectA.jar sucessfully?

Comment: Do you build from intellij Idea?

Comment: @JonathanJohx It is successfully run with intellij idea. However it is failed to build it with gradle **build** task.

Comment: @JonathanJohx I want to build a jar so that I must use **gradle build task** to generate jar file.